# Flutter, how to update reactive list declared in first screen controller from the second screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using GetX in my project. Lets suppose I have two screens. Each screen have a button.
The controller of first screen have observable list of objects. When a button in first screen is pressed, one of the object list is sent to second screen.

In second screen user changes the value of the data received and when `save` button is pressed, I want to update the observable list in first screen as well.

I know I can use `Get.back()` to send updated data back to first screen. I could do following in second screen

```
Get.back(result: [
    {"updatedObject": listDetails}
]);
```

And in first screen I could do

```
Get.to(() => SecondScreen(), arguments: [
   {"list": listDetails[index]}
]).then((result) {
    // result[0]["updatedObject"]  // use this to update list observable
});
```

**My Question.**
Can I update list in first screen without navigating back to first screen when `Save` button is pressed.

I am pretty new with GetX and i am trying to learn it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long that when you navigate to the second screen using `Get.to()` then you can always access the data in the controller of the first screen using `Get.find()`.

Here's a sample I tweaked it a little bit:

```
Get.to(() => SecondScreen(), arguments: 
   {"index": index},
)
```

On the controller on the second screen you can access(view/update) the data using the index.

```
@override
void onInit() {
   index = Get.arguments['index'];
   // View
   name = Get.find<FirstScreenController>().listDetails[index].name;
   print(name);
   // Update
   Get.find<FirstScreenController>().listDetails[index].name = "John";
}
```